# How to infer the atomic energy levels from the observed energy differences?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

I am always curious about this point. By spectroscopy, we can determine the energy differences. But how to determine the zero point, or the values of the levels themselves?

Answer (score 5):

The energy levels are given with respect to the [ionization level](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hmbase/hyde.html), considered zero, here for the hydrogen atom.

[image: hydrogen]

The ionisation energy of the ground state of an atom could be measured by the  maximum frequency needed to ionize the  atom.

The [Bohr model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hmbase/hyde.html) is sufficient to determine the ground level of hydrogen, using the series fits to the spectra.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to define the zero level, for example, as the energy of a state at the boundary between the discrete and continuous spectra.